# Is there any difference between using Java DB and Derby?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby, javadb

I am new to Java-based databases. I want to start with Java DB as it comes as a part of JDK. I cannot find enough resources to understand: is Java DB and Apache Derby the same thing? If yes, which one is easier to use from Eclipse? Is it solely command line based database system?

I tried to follow the official Getting Started guide for Java DB which says

> The Java DB product includes Derby without any modification whatsoever to the underlying source code.

but I cannot figure out the best way to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JavaDB` is the the oracle supported version of `Apache Derby` (some kind of fork), technically the same exact functionality (same documentation).

> ```
> which one is easier to use from Eclipse?
> ```

So there is no difference from the Eclipse part.

Otherwise, think of [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) as the best alternative of `Derby (JavaDB)`, fairly [faster](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html) and [simple](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html) to use, [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/) will be a good complement  as database migration tool (and a good practice).

Comment: I considered H2 but from what I read it has minor stability issues. Anyway, is it all command line administration for pure Java databases? Nothing more user-friendly?

Answer (score 2):

As a tool to use with Derby, try Squirrel: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

It's a great tool, and it works very well with Derby.